# How to get CDocument for derived CMFCShellTreeCtl on an Outlook Style MFC program?

Tags: mfc

I am new to MFC and have built an "outlook" style MFC app using the wizard.  I've extended the `CMFCShellTreetCtrl` using `CMyShellTreeCtrl` and had data member variables and all was working fine.   Now I want to move the data over to the `CDocument` class. Since there is several accesses to the data as each item is clicked or enumerated, I thought I would create a member variable `m_pDoc` to access the public variables in the `CDocument`.  The problem I'm having, I can't find where to get the `CDocument` as it appears it's not setup when the trees `OnCreate` is called.  That is in `OnCreate`

```
CWnd* pWndMain = AfxGetMainWnd();
ASSERT(pWndMain);
ASSERT(pWndMain->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CFrameWnd)) &&  !pWndMain->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMDIFrameWnd))); // Not an SDI app.
m_pDoc = (CMyDoc*) ((CFrameWnd*)pWndMain)->GetActiveDocument();
```

returns `NULL` in m_pDoc and if I tried in an `AfterCreate()` (which is called after `CreateOutlookBar`) it's too late as m_pDoc is already being used and get a crash.

```
    // Create and setup "Outlook" navigation bar:
    if (!CreateOutlookBar(m_wndNavigationBar, ID_VIEW_NAVIGATION, m_wndTree, m_wndCalendar, 250))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create navigation pane\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
  m_wndTree.AfterCreate();
```

Any Ideas?

TIA!!

Comment: Your base class is a control and not a CView derived control. Therefore, it won't have a document associated with it.  It might be a child window of a CView derived class which has a document...  Or, you can look at classes like CEditView or CTreeView to see how MFC implements a CView derived class based on a control.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following but I'm not sure if this is the proper way.  Again, I'm new to MFC (I always have used Win32 directly).  This works so it's *AN* answer, but is it *THE* correct answer?

```
  POSITION docpos = AfxGetApp()->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
  CDocTemplate *doctemplate = AfxGetApp()->GetNextDocTemplate(docpos);
  docpos=doctemplate->GetFirstDocPosition();
  m_pDoc = (CMyDoc*)doctemplate->GetNextDoc(docpos);
  ASSERT(m_pDoc);
  ASSERT(m_pDoc->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc)));
```

TIA!!